# 9-13 (how to describe this)

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I am having difficulty describing this:

> "If you see a **single number (9)** then you need to buy only one, 
>   but if you see **two ranged numbers(9-10),** then you have to purchase
>   the items according to what it says."

What is the correct word choice for this?
Should it be "**two different numbers showing it has a range**" or something?

Comment: a pair of numbers, joined by a dash, representing a range

Comment: @MichaelHarvey It took me three reads, but eventually, from what I understood, John meant how to actually use the word range.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, hmm nice, you hit the nail on the head there. I think you really have to describe it as there is no noun of it that exists in English right?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/range), "range" is both a **noun** and a **verb**, and can be used, of course, in both ways. In other words, you use it like you use any noun, or like you use any verb. Examples (taken from the definition of the word from the link above) are listed below.

*Range* as a **noun**:

- The price range is from $100 to $500.
- The product is aimed at young people in the 18–25 age range.

*Range* as a **verb**:

- Dress sizes range from petite to extra large.
- Prices range between $50 and $250.

In the specific instance you provided the word range is used like so:

- A numbers range. (**noun**)
- Ranging between 9 and 10. (**verb**)
- A range of numbers. (**noun**)

Comment: I'm not asking for their meanings, thx anyway. It's already been answered by harvey.

Answer (score 0):

*Through* is used if the range consists of 3 or more items and you want to say "starting from X until Y".

> If you see 7 then you only need to buy one, but if you see 8 through 10 then you have to purchase items according to what is says

If the range consists of 2 items, use *or*

> If you see 7 then you only need to buy one, but if you see 8 or 9 then you have to purchase items according to what is says

Of course, if decimal/fractions are selectable then your range has more than 2 items and *through* can be used.  But if things like 7.9, 7.8, etc. are possible, you have to account for that.

> If you see anything under but not including 8 then you only need to buy one, but if you see 8 through 9 then you have to purchase items according to what is says

Comment: This is a breakdown of it perhaps, but it's not the answer to what is being asked. Thx anyway.